# PHP - function parameter type long

Tags: php, parameters

I wonder how php implemented that 'flag' arguments for some functions:

```
glob( "argument as string" , GLOB_MARK )
```

In the official documentation it's flag is declared as integer:

```
array glob ( string $pattern [, int $flags = 0 ] )
```

Skeptically I tried to implement it:

```
function a(int $a){ var_dump($a); }    a(FLAG);
```

Like expected it throws an error that constant 'FLAG' isn't defined.
So I realy wonder: How I could do such cool things too, preventing a constant for 'FLAG'.

Comment: You just need to define your constants: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: The difference is that you are trying to add default arguments to actual parameters. From where a is called FLAG is indeed not defined. What they are doing is defining the default formal parameter. Your example and theirs is not same in any way,

Answer (score 0):

you just need to define your constants before it's usage using `define`

```
define("FLAG", "foo");
```

Then you should use it normally.

```
function a(int $a) { 
    var_dump($a); 
}    
a(FLAG);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php